# Connecting two promises in a Firebase web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am using a Realtime Database to handle some data in a Firebase web app.
In the code hereafter, I want to insert a record in the DB only if fieldOne and fieldTwo aren't going to be duplicated.

```
dbReference.orderByChild("fieldOne").equalTo(fieldOneVal).once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    alert('This fieldOne has already been used.')
    reject();
  }
}).then( // What is the correct way to connect this line and the following ??
dbReference.orderByChild("fieldTwo").equalTo(fieldTwoVal).once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    alert('This NAME has already been used.')
    reject();
  }

  // All is now OK.
  .... do the final things here .....
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
  alert('This record cannot be inserted.')
});
```

At this point, I am able to tweak the code to make things work the way I wish. But my issue is that I am not doing things the proper way (I know that due to some messages I can see in the console). The comment in my code shows where I need to know the correct way to connect the two parts.
*What is the .... the following ??*

For information the DB looks like this:

```
MyList
  + -M93j....443cxYYDSN
      fieldOne: "asdc..."
      fieldTwo: "Gkk...."
  + -M94j.........OZS6FL
      fieldOne: "afc..."
      fieldTwo: "SDFSk...."
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of your database please?

Comment: I have updated the post so you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Promises chaining combined with errors throwing should do the trick.

```
  dbReference
    .orderByChild('fieldOne')
    .equalTo(fieldOneVal)
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        throw new Error('fieldOneExists');
      }
      return dbReference
        .orderByChild('fieldTwo')
        .equalTo(fieldTwoVal)
        .once('value');
    })
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        throw new Error('fieldTwoExists');
      }

      // All is now OK.
      //.... do the final things here .....
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      if (
        error.message === 'fieldOneExists' ||
        error.message === 'fieldTwoExists'
      ) {
        console.log('This record cannot be inserted');
      } else {
        console.log('other error');
      }
    });
```

---

However, it would probably be better to use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for checking the existence of the two values for the `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` fields.

The problem is that the Realtime Database transactions don't work with queries: you need to exactly know the location of the data to be modified (or to be checked for existence/non-existence). So you would need to adapt your data model if it appears that you really need a transaction (which depends on your exact global requirements).

For example you could create database nodes with the concatenation of the values of `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` values and check the existence of such a node in a Transaction. But, again, the feasibility of this approach depends on your exact global requirements, which we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the hasChild() method.

```
if(snapshot.hasChild('name') {
   // ... do stuff !
}
```

Or,

create a new node in your firebase real-time db named as usernames and add each username in this list. In future before inserting a new username check if it's present in this list